# HSQLDB Spring user lack privileges

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hsqldb

My project is using JDBC and Spring 3.

As my little project grows I need some tests. I want to create Integration tests for my DAO layer but I can't  get it to work with an embedded HSQL database.

Here is the error I get : `Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: name`

My configuration :

```
CREATE SCHEMA GIVEMEASHOW 

-- USE_CASE TABLE
CREATE TABLE SHOW (
    ID                          BIGINT          GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    NAME                        VARCHAR(255)    DEFAULT NULL,
    ICON_URL                    VARCHAR(255)    DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_SHOW_NAME UNIQUE (NAME)
);
```

My test :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations =
{ "classpath:gmas-db-cfg-test.xml" })
public class ShowDaoIT
{
    public static Logger    LOGGER  = Logger.getLogger(ShowDaoIT.class.getName());

    @Inject
    ShowDao                 showDao;

    @Test
    public void saveIT()
    {
        Show show = new Show();
        show.setIconUrl("show1_banner.png");
        show.setName("show1");
        showDao.save(show);
        showDao.list();
    }
}
```

The dao method :

```
@Override
    public void save(final Show show)
    {
        LOGGER.info("Saving a new Show");
        try
        {
            final String query = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " (name, icon_url) " + "VALUES (?, ?)";

            jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator()
            {

                public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException
                {
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query, new String[]
                    { "name", "icon_url" });
                    ps.setString(1, show.getName());
                    ps.setString(2, show.getIconUrl());
                    return ps;
                }
            }, keyHolder);
            show.setId(keyHolder.getKey().intValue());

        } catch (final Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Everything is working on my mysql database, my website is working correctly. I'm just not able to set integrations test on the dao layer.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use an HSQLDB Server for your tests. The server can serve a mem: database if required.